# rotate image in css for ie6

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

i need to rotate image in css for ie6

is it possile

i tried Below code But none of Below is working

```
.image-box

{ 

-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=2);  /* IE6,IE7 */

-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=2);  /* IE6,IE7 */

 ms-filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=2); /* IE8 */

 -ms-filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=2); /* IE8 */

 transform: rotate(180deg);

-moz-transform: rotate(180deg);

-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);

-ms-transform: rotate(180deg);

  -sand-transform:  <rotate(180deg)>;


 }
```

please help!!!

Comment: Stop supporting IE-6 even microsoft wants this now :)

Comment: You sure you don't want it to be compatible with Netscape Navigator as well?

Comment: You shouldn't. http://www.ie6countdown.com

Comment: i want the css to compatible with each & every version of ie

Comment: @ Sean Dunwoody .....ie6 & above

Comment: @Omkaara - In all seriousness, to support IE6 -- especially if you want features like rotation -- you will be adding a heck of a lot of work for yourself, with very little gain (because no-one uses IE6 any more anyway). Also, even though the `filter` option does work, it has some very large bugs and quirks which mean even if you can do it, it's not always worthwhile doing it.

Comment: most developers I know are dropping support for IE7 as well now. IE6 is long gone. Please please abandon it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not supposed to have a hyphen before non vendor specific CSS properties. Remove the hyphen from `-filter: ...`:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=2);  /* IE6,IE7 */
```

Additionally, you might need to trigger `hasLayout` by adding `overflow:auto` or `zoom:1` to your CSS. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/xvbFG/) is a demonstration (I've tested this in IE7 using browserlabs).

Comment: Note that this rotates things by 180 degrees, if your element is symmetric about the x axis, you won't really notice.

Comment: i want image to be upside down (rotate)

Comment: +1 this is the correct answer. If it still doesn't work, then you may be hitting other IE6 bugs or missing features. Supporting IE6 is hard. Don't say we didn't warn you.

Answer (score 0):

IE6 has limited support, even from MS.  You probably should use IE conditional comments to provide a different image or markup for IE6.  Here's the MSDN article on these http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the info, i rarely support IE6, i just put up a message telling the user to upgrade to IE8 or Chrome.  I find that so any things don't work, even in IE8 that conditional comments are usually a good choice.